# How to update primefaces attribute?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, disabled-input, ajax-update

I have a `<p:commandButton disabled="#{scannerStatus.disabled}" actionListener="#{scannerStatus.activate}" id="button-id"/>`

In scannerStatus I have:
`private boolean disabled;` // plus geters and setters

```
public void activate() {
        this.setDisabled(true);
        boolean status = doAnAction(); // This takes some seconds

        if (!status) {
            doSomething();
        } else {
            this.setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the `disabled` attribute of the commandButton does not change when `this.setDisabled(true)` line from `activate` method is called.

I need some seconds the `disabled` attribute from the commandButton to be `true`.

The `disabled` property is set back to false and then the `disabled` attribute from commandButton is updated. So the update in commandButton takes place after the function ends.

How can I update the attribute of the commandButton when the `this.setDisabled(true)` in the method activate?

I have tried to use
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("button-id");`
after the `this.setDisabled` but it's not working.

Comment: @sinclair: Note that OP expected the `this.setDisabled(true)` to be immediately visible in the client side even before `boolean status = doAnAction()` is executed. Your link thus only answers the Y part of his http://xyproblem.info, not the X part.

Comment: How can you call the action listener if the button is initially disabled?

Comment: The button is not initially disabled. The button must be disabled for a few seconds after the actionListener was called.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this should do it:

```
<p:commandButton 
 actionListener="#{scannerStatus.activate}" 
 id="button-id"
 onstart="document.getElementById('button-id').disabled = true;"
 oncomplete="document.getElementById('button-id').disabled = false;" />
```